# Browserify hangs with 100% cpu usage when trying to compile .vue component

Tags: vue.js, browserify, vuejs2, vue-component

Gulpfile

```
const elixir = require('laravel-elixir');
const gulp = require('gulp');
const watch = require('gulp-watch');
require('laravel-elixir-vueify'); 
require('laravel-elixir-vue-2')

function domix() {
    elixir(mix => {
        mix.copy('resources/assets/js/', 'public/js/');
        mix.copy('resources/assets/css/', 'public/css/');
        mix.copy('resources/assets/img/', 'public/img/');
        mix.copy('resources/assets/fonts/', 'public/fonts/');
        mix.browserify('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app-vue.js')
    });
}

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    return watch('resources/assets/**/*.{js,css,vue}', domix);
});

gulp.task("default", domix);

domix();
```

What I see in console

```
[11:52:41] Starting 'copy'...
[11:52:41] Finished 'copy' after 82 ms
[11:52:41] Starting 'browserify'...
```

And after last line it hangs with 100% cpu usage.

If I remove line `mix.browserify('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app-vue.js')` it works fine.

Content of `app.js`

```
import Vue from "vue"
import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
Vue.use(VueResource)

const infiniteScroll = require("vue-infinite-scroll");
Vue.use(infiniteScroll)

Vue.component("vue-log", require("./components/vue-log.vue"));

window.VueBus = new Vue();

Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = document.querySelector('meta[name=csrf_token]').content;

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#page-content'
});
```

If I remove

```
Vue.component("vue-log", require("./components/vue-log.vue"));
```

browserify works fine

The component is very simple

```
<template>
<div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            currentPage: 1,
            lastPage: 1
        }
    },
    methods: {
        loadNextPage() {
            if(this.currentPage < this.lastPage) {
                console.log("load next page " + this.currentPage + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Remove body of `loadNextPage` method and it compiles.

Comment: tag BROWSERIFY rather than Vue as it looks more like Browserify issue

Comment: Are you applying the `browserify` transforms in your `package.json`? This can sometimes happen if you try to apply the transforms via `gulp` and `package.json` simultaneously.

Comment: Propably it is the case.